# Greyhound bus tracker - No schedules found

Tags: usa, public-transport, greyhound, indiana, indianapolis

According to the Greyhound website (if you search through "book a trip"), there are 3 buses every day from Bloomington, IN to Indianapolis, IN:

[image]

It looks like the schedule numbers are constant and do not depend on the day. I tried looking up these schedules on [bus tracker](http://bustracker.greyhound.com/) and got "No schedules found". And if I try searching through "SEARCH BY DEPARTURE CITY OR ARRIVAL CITY" instead of "SEARCH BY SCHEDULE NUMBER", there are no buses from Bloomington, IN. Also, these 3 routes are not displayed in [this list](https://bustracker.greyhound.com/route-finder/).

Is this some kind of bag with the Greyhound website? Does the the tracking option not work for this route?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Greyhound BusTracker is not available for every bus on every route, as it depends on the location and transmission equipment being installed and operational on the vehicle.

In particular, note that not all tickets sold on Greyhound.com are actually operated by Greyhound itself, as Greyhound is a major broker for tickets on numerous partner bus lines. This is analogous to airline codesharing. If you view the actual itinerary, there is a section marked "Operating Carrier."

In this case, Greyhound does not actually run any buses between Bloomington to Indianapolis, which explains its absence from the route list and from BusTracker. When you buy a ticket on Greyhound.com, you are actually buying a ticket for [Hoosier Ride](https://hoosierride.com/), which Greyhound sells on behalf of its partner, Miller Transportation. Hoosier Ride, unfortunately, does not appear to offer anything like BusTracker.

Comment: I think Hoosier Ride does have a tracking option: http://miller.myatiportal.com/. But I still can't see any buses departing from Bloomington. Probably their tracker doesn't work at all.

Comment: Yes, I saw that link, and I stand by my statement. They may have had such a service a few years ago, but the fact that not a single bus displays for any city, and that the word "tracker" appears nowhere on their website now, suggests that it has been discontinued.

Comment: Interesting. So it appears that there is no any way to know whether the bus is on time... I actually happened to be on the bus stop the other day, and I haven't seen the 6:05 bus between 5:50 and 6:15. What should the passengers do in such cases? Or should I ask a separate question about this?

Comment: You can do what everyone did before tracking was even possible: call the company and ask for news. Some companies might also send alerts if there is a major problem. A handful might post to social media. If this is too much uncertainty for you, I suggest taking a shuttle, renting a car, or finding a carpool—there are always people traveling between back and forth between the university and the big city (or at least its airport). The Bloomington rideshare Facebook group has over 3,000 members.

Comment: @user77409 This is the USA.  Public transportation sucks.  What you do is get frustrated and annoyed about a first world country without a proper intercity passenger rail system.  That's exactly what I did when I took the bus from Madison to Minneapolis-Saint Paul 6 years ago and was waiting for over an hour, not having a clue if the bus to would ever come (and I was going to catch an intercontinental flight).

Comment: @gerrit In such an expansive country, with a very dispersed population, very inexpensive fuel, and a strong culture of independence and individualism, not to mention anti-elitism, the political will to spend public money on empty trains connecting East Bumblef^ck to New Timbuktu just isn't going to be there. Get used to it. Greyhound and the other incumbents' primary competition is the passenger car for the foreseeable future. In parts of the country where people actually use buses, they have improved greatly due to new competition from the likes of  Megabus and Flixbus.

Comment: You can skip the expansiveness and cheap fuel causes, and consider only culture, because that's the only reason. Russia is larger, less populated and has cheap fuel, yet it has plenty of intercity or suburban rail, and US public transit still sucks in densely populated areas. Americans chose to build their cities the way they do, Americans chose to get rid of streetcars and most intercity rail when people started to have private cars, and Americans chose to not invest in public transportation either within or between cities. It was among the most important reasons for me to return to Europe.

Comment: It's a frequently repeated and probably frequently believed myth that the poor public transportation in the USA would have anything to do with natural geography — it does not. And I think the people of Indianapolis (2M) and Bloomington (85k), 80 km apart, or those of Madison (650k) and Minneapolis-Saint Paul (4M), 430 km apart, would not consider themselves to be East Bumblefuck or New Timbuktu.

Comment: We aren't exactly going to resolve this question here, but my ultimate point is that where there is demand for better buses, there are better buses. You can get from Ithaca to New York by bus for $90 in great comfort. But the overwhelming majority of people take the $30 bus instead, or drive, even though there are no interstates to Ithaca (which get blamed for the demise of railroads, even though their decline started decades earlier). Your petulance about American transportation is equaled only by obnoxious American tourists complaining about parking in Europe.